# Moving MySites from their own web application to existing intranet

Tags: migration, my-site, web-application

At the moment we have a Sharepoint 2007 based intranet located at hxxps://intranet.example.com and the My Sites are located at hxxps://my.example.com

What we'd like to do is move the my sites so that they sit under hxxps://intranet.example.com/mysite.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

may i ask why you want to do this? It is considered a best practice to keep my sites in a seperate web applications.

I have actually done the exact opposite using [stsadm -o mergecontentdbs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262923%28office.12%29.aspx)

[My post on splitting up sites](http://sites.wizdim.com/andersrask/sharepoint/moving-my-sites-to-a-separate-web-application), if its any use.

Comment: We're having problems with external users getting many login prompts e.g. all the photos are stored on the mysite so when they open any page that has photos on the intranet they have to login again to get access to the photos.

Comment: this solvable: Internally you can roll out a Group Policy that adds the mysite and intranet to intranet zone (only needed if you had fully qualified urls, like http://intranet.company.com and http://my.company.com). For extranet users this might be harder depending on your setup, but if you tell them to add the sites to the same trusted zone it will work without prompts

Answer (score 0):

You would create a new My Site host under intranet.example.com with the same type of configuration you have at my.example.com.

We're in the opposite boat, our My Sites are under the same web application and will be moving them out to a new URL.  Having them all intermixed within the collaboration sites and content databases is problematic (for us).

having them separate will allow us to have better control over where the My Sites reside and allow differing SLAs in terms of content backup and recovery.